# Is there a conventional iterator interface in Java which separates traversal from element access?

Tags: java, iterator

For my application, element access is expensive, so java.util.Iterator is no use.  I want something more like C++ iterators, where I can move the pointer around without returning an element.  Is there something in the standard library like this, or has some de facto standard interface evolved through custom?  (If not, please don't waste your time posting code snippets - I'm quite able to think up reasonable names which will do the job).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "element access is expensive"?

Comment: The elements being traversed over reside on a remote system, and I don't want to fetch them unnecessarily.

Comment: To the extent of my knowledge there's no interface in the standard API that suits you (i.e. an interface with something like `iterator.skip()`). The best solution using standard API methods I believe, would be to do `yourList.sublist(startIndex).iterator()` for instance.

Comment: ...alternatively, if the rest of your code base is compatible with it (you're not relying on `getClass()`, not using hibernate, you're iterating over an interface type etc.) you could implement `next()` so that it returns a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` which fetches the underlying object lazily.

Comment: OK, I should probably write my own interface instead of trying to shoehorn something into Iterator.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: That sounds like the only sane thing to do. Keep in mind that you can always extend `java.util.Iterator`. That way your own iterator can pass as a regular iterator (which could be useful whenever all elements needs to be accessed anyway).

Comment: Just for the record, I think your question is a very valid one, and very applicable to real life scenarios. The solution to a lazy de-referencer where you only access data when needed is not always possible.

Comment: @fizzer, any thoughts on my answer? Do you want me to elaborate on something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since no one came around to write a proper answer, I'll expand my comments into an answer.)

To the extent of my knowledge there's no interface in the standard API that suits you (i.e. an interface with something like `iterator.skip()`). The best solution using standard API methods I believe, would be to do `yourList.sublist(startIndex).iterator()` for instance.

I think that, if possible, you should consider creating your own iterator interface. (Note that you can let it extend the `java.util.Iterator` interface to be able to use it as an ordinary iterator if needed.)

Finally, and this is mostly for future readers that *have* to use `java.util.Iterator` and *have* to access the underlying list lazily, you can use a [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). Note that `Proxy` objects doesn't always play well with serialization / persistence libraries, and it requires that you work with interfaces. An example follows:

Here's a **slow** `OnDiskList` that fetches line *n* in each call to `get(int n)`:

```
class OnDiskList extends AbstractList<CharSequence> {

    // Slow list access method: Linear search for n:th line.
    @Override
    public CharSequence get(int n) {
        System.out.println("Fetching line " + n + "...");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("big-file.txt"))) {
            return lines.skip(n).findFirst().get();
        } catch (IOException shouldBeHandled) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Here's how the output looks when using an ordinary iterator:

```
Iterator<CharSequence> normalIter = onDiskList.iterator();
normalIter.next(); // Skip
normalIter.next(); // Skip
normalIter.next(); // Skip
System.out.println(normalIter.next()); // Print
```

**Output:**

```
Fetching line 0...
Fetching line 1...
Fetching line 2...
Fetching line 3...
Line 3 in big-file.txt
```

Now to the magic: Here's a `ProxyingIterator` that hides the object behind a `Proxy` that accesses the list lazily:

```
class ProxyingIterator implements Iterator<CharSequence> {

    List<CharSequence> slowList;
    int pos = 0;

    public ProxyingIterator(List<CharSequence> slowList) {
        this.slowList = slowList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return pos < slowList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence next() {
        return (CharSequence) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                        CharSequence.class.getClassLoader(),
                        new Class[] { CharSequence.class },
                        new LazyLoadingInvocationHandler(pos++));
    }

    private class LazyLoadingInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        int index;
        CharSequence loadedObject = null;

        public LazyLoadingInvocationHandler(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
            if (loadedObject == null)
                loadedObject = slowList.get(index);
            try {
                return method.invoke(loadedObject, args);
            } catch (Exception shouldNotHappen) {
                shouldNotHappen.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When using this iterator it looks as follows:

```
Iterator<CharSequence> proxyingIter = new ProxyingIterator(onDiskList);
proxyingIter.next(); // Skip
proxyingIter.next(); // Skip
proxyingIter.next(); // Skip
System.out.println(proxyingIter.next()); // Print
```

**Output:**

```
Fetching line 3...
Line 3 in big-file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

java.util.Iterator is an interface, not an implementation. The behaviour of your iterator will depend on the collection you are using and how you obtained it.

Most of them should not be doing anything expensive as, for Objects, Java passes around their reference. Whatever you're accessing that is expensive should be abstracted away behind an Object that allows you to refer to it without trying to access it.

If your gripe is instead with the interface and a desire for other methods, then you'll need to come up with and conform to that interface by yourself; java.util.Iterator *is* the conventional iterator for Java, in part likely for the reasons I've mentioned.

Comment: Note that `java.util.Iterator` says that `next()` should return an object, so moving around forces you to access the underlying data structure. (And btw, don't say java passes objects by reference. Lists doesn't hold objects, objects aren't passed around at all.)

Comment: @aioobe can you give me an example of Java passing Objects around by value?

Comment: No. As I said, objects aren't passed at all. Reference to objects are passed around though (but they are passed by value).

Comment: @aioobe Now that I think about it, I suppose you're right that pass-by-reference has slightly different results. What's the correct term for it? Pass by alias?

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [Evaluation Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

Comment: Call by sharing, then.

Comment: *However, the term "call by sharing" is not in common use; the terminology is inconsistent across different sources. For example, in the Java community, they say that Java is pass-by-value*

Comment: In the context of this Question, telling someone familiar with C++ iterators and, by extension, C++ itself, that Java passes by value would be rather misleading, and just because a whole community does it, doesn't mean they are right. At this point I am resigning myself to the fact that no matter what terminology one uses, it will require further qualification.

Comment: You make a good point, but I'm not buying it fully. Java has nothing that corresponds to C++ references, so mentioning references when explaining Javas evaluation strategy may be confusing, especially to a C++ programmer. A Java reference is much more similar to a C++ pointer, and pointers are (typically) passed by value in C++. Anyway, this is already off topic.